# How to interpret "to + verb + and + verb"?

Tags: meaning

> If you **fail to park properly and scan** the barcode at the parking zone,
>   you will be charged a $XX.

In the example above, does it mean "if you fail to park properly and if you fail to scan the barcode" or "if you fail to park properly, and then if you scan the barcode"?

Comment: Have you looked up parallel sentence structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a colloquial structure. It could rewritten:

You must park properly and scan the barcode, otherwise you will be charged ...